# How do you filter a list response using a graphql query in Sangria

Tags: graphql, sangria

I am running a graphQL server on Sangria (scala). Here is an example query:

```
query {
  missions { 
    missionId { id } ,
    name
  }
}
```

and a sample response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "missions": [
      {
        "missionId": {
          "id": "mission1"
        },
        "name": "foo"
      },
      {
        "missionId": {
          "id": "mission2"
        },
        "name": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am looking for a query that filters the list and only returns the element having `mission1` as id?

Answer (score 0):

You need implement pagination. Pass `limit`(`pageSize`) argument to `graphql` server `resolver`. process the datas in server-side.

```
query {
  missions(limit: 1) { 
    missionId { id } ,
    name
  }
}
```

server-side:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    missions: (_, {limit}, ctx) => {
      const missions = [];

      for(let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        missions.push(db.missions[i])
      }
      return missions;
    }
  }
}
```

That's `graphql` ideology, front-end developer define the data structure and what data they want to get.

It's bad idea to query the `list` data through a http request. And `filter` the data in front-end using `directive` or other way of `graphql`. Waste bandwidth.

Comment: I see what you mean, I was however looking for a filter, i.e. `missions(missionId(id: "mission1"))` but it sounds like this is also something that has to be implemented server side?

Comment: @reikje Yes. it is. You should not filter the data in client-side.